# Mathematics of simple performance testing

Tags: dataset, optimal-scaling, database

I have a set of sorted tables **T** that have known but different dimensions. There are two types of functions in this system:

1. f(**T**)
2. g(**T**, n), where n is an integer parameter.

... and two types of costs as well:

1. c(f(**T**, n))
2. c(g(**T**, n))

... and there are a few things I believe to happen on average:

1. c(g(**T**, a)) < c(g(**T**, b), for a < b
2. c(f(**T**, a)) > c(g(**T**, b), for a < b

Now, I cannot directly formulate an objective function with both c(f(**T**, n)) and c(g(**T**, n)) since the two costs are incurred at very different occasions. However, I would still want to learn something about the parameter n.

What kind of analysis do you think would be helpful?

So far, I recorded the c(g(T_i, n)) for all T_i under a spectrum of n's (with 3 replicates). I already learned that:

|T_i| and c(g(T_i, n)) have a Pearson correlation > 0.95, for large n

However, I have not done any recordings on c(f(T_i, n)) yet since it's time-expensive to obtain (which is why I decide to gather my thoughts in here before proceeding).

Admittedly, I am an amataur in stats. I know how to do chi-squared, f-test, fisher's, z-test, t-test, etc on paper but this is the first time I am thinking about using them in practice. Again, any heads up on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

In case the gurus here deem this question to be outside of the scope of MathOverflow, I also formulated my problem in a different way in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925628/basic-statistical-analysis-of-database-optimization-strategy).

Note: This is a [repost](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181251/mathematics-of-simple-performance-testing?noredirect=1#comment454575_181251) from MathOverflow since I did not know there's a statistics section in StackExchange until a responder mentioned it.

Comment: Check the page of the help about what's [on topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), specifically the part that says "*cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated*". If you post somewhat similar questions emphasizing specific aspects of the question to suit the specific subsites, that would probably be reasonable, but if you're inclined to post exactly the same information here because you think it's better suited here, you should migrate the original.

Comment: In fact the original *has* now been migrated. So now we're left with two copies. Please delete this one and edit the other post's tags.